# Kafka server can't running while it will not attempt to authenticate using SSAL (unknown error)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i have a problem with kafka server.

i have done running apache druid with its port 2080, while zookeeper kafka with its port 2181 to avoid crushing a zookeeper between druid and kakfa.

i dont have any problem with druid because it running correctly, and kafka zookeeper well too.

but when i try to run kafka server following this syntax:

```
./bin/kafka-server-star.sh config/server.properties
```

with its configuration:

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:9092
```

i have issue that the error say it will not attempt authenticate using SSAL (unknow error) like the picture i drop below:[try to connect kafka server getting error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiEBv.png)

i used to well, but i dont know it going not well. everyone can help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to `zookeeper.connect` property in `server.properties` Kafka configuration file.

`zookeeper.connect` should point to zookeeper connection string or quorum. From your example, I guess `zookeeper.connect` property is pointing to Kafka server port, 9092, itself. Since there is no zookeeper server running on the given address `localhost:9092`, zookeeper-client fails to connect to zookeeper server and throws below error

```
Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9092. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

Zookeeper server port, which is configured using name `clientPort`, can be found in `zookeeper.properties` configuration file.

Please try with following setting

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:<clientPort, 2181 by default>
```

Zookeeper connection string is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zookeeper server.

**Examples:**

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
```

You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the root directory for all Kafka znodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to lower your jdk version. I solved it by using `jdk-11`.